# 1062 - Duplicate entry 'button_buynow' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I know this has been discussed before but when I read the other threads, they don't seem to address my problem.

When I try to run the SQL query in PhpMyAdmin, I get the error :

**#1062 - Duplicate entry 'button_buynow' for key 'PRIMARY'**

I am sure the table was empty prior to me running the query so I don't know what's going on. Can somebody shed a light?

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `buttons` (
      `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
      `value` text NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY  (`name`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

    --
    -- Dumping data for table `buttons`
    --

    INSERT INTO `buttons` (`name`, `value`) VALUES
    ('button_buynow', 'buynowCC_LG.gif'),
    ('button_addtocart', 'x-click-but41.gif'),
    ('button_viewcart', 'viewcart_LG.gif'),
    ('button_freedownload', 'downloadnow.jpg');
```

Comment: Check your table, sure, you should have that row with the value `button_buynow`

Comment: Insert query might have executed twice. delete all the rows and try to insert again.

Comment: These queries run successfully on my system for first time, Again try the insert query it shows your error, because the name field is primary key.

Comment: no issue as far I can see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ab0e59/1/0

Answer (score 0):

> *I am sure the table was empty prior to me running the query so I don't know what's going on.*

If you're sure that the table was empty you might have **a trigger** defined on this table that is the cause of this error.

You can check it this way

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM information_schema.triggers
 WHERE trigger_schema = schema()
   AND event_object_table = 'buttons'
```

If you do in fact have a trigger then you either fix it or just drop it.

Comment: Did it help? Did you resolve your problem? Do you need more help with your question?